# Can Rails & Django (now) query more than one database at a time?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, django

***EDIT:*** Since you are asking for specifics, consider a photo-sharing site (like Flickr or picasa - - I know that one uses PHP, while the other uses Python) for instance. If it proves to be successful, it needs to scale enormously. I hope this is specific enough.

It's been sometime since I heard any discussion on this, and since I am in the decision making process of choosing between Ruby and Python for a web project, here come the questions:

[1] Can current versions of Rails (Ruby) and Django (Python) query more than one database at a time?

[2] I also read on SO that "If your focus is building web-sites or web-applications go Ruby" (because it has fully featured, web-focused Rails). But that was about 2 years ago. What's the state of Python web framework Django today? Is it head-to-head with Rails now?

**EDIT:** [3] Don't know if I can ask this here, it's really surprising how quickly the Stack Exchange sites load. Do SE sites still use the same technology [mentioned here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)? If not, does anyone have an update?

Comment: in [1] you are asking whether Ruby-on-Rails and Django can work with more than one database at a time, right?  Because otherwise the question makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @Dmitry Beransky : Right. I will edit the Q right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in either of the languages that would prevent you from connecting to more than one database at a time. The real question is why would you want to?

The reason the StackOverflow sites are so fast is not so much the choice of technology but they way it's applied. Database optimization techniques are largely independent of the platform involved, just based on common-sense principles and proven methods of scaling.

Ruby on Rails offers a number of methods for connecting to multiple databases, though you might mean connecting to a system that's divided into shards, into multi-tenant partitions, or where different forms of data are stored on different databases. All of these approaches are supported, but they are quite different in implementation.

You should post a new question with an outline of the problem you're trying to solve if you want a specific answer.

Comment: Edited Q again: Please consider a photo-sharing site for instance.

Comment: You can't scale something if you don't have scaling problems, and you don't have scaling problems if you haven't built it. The only way to scale something effectively is to carefully investigate performance problems and find solutions. A good way to expose these early is to run large-scale simulations of expected usage patterns, such as uploading 10 million photos and making a large number of queries per second. Without testing, you're just shooting in the dark and will waste a lot of time.

Comment: A "photo sharing site" could mean anything. Maybe it's the "friend" feature that causes performance problems. Maybe it's resizing the images or applying effects. You will have to build a quick prototype to see where the problems are. Premature optimization will slow down your development process considerably, and often your intuition will guide you to optimize the easy, irrelevant things, not the hard and important things.

Comment: Remember that you optimize the things that take the longest aggregate time first, not the slowest things. A minute-long operation that runs a dozen times a day gets fixed after the two second operation that runs a million times a day.

Comment: Whatever application you build for launch will most likely be replaced entirely as your application grows and scales. There is no scale-proof application, and the only application without scaling problems is one that's not growing.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-database support exists in Django.  In our Django project we have models pulling data from Postgres, MySQL, Oracle, and MS SQL Server (there are various issues depending on the database, but it all generally works).  From what I've read, RoR supports multiple databases as well.  Each framework comes with its own set of strengths and weaknesses which you have to evaluate against your particular needs and requirements.  I don't think anyone can give you a (valid/useful) general answer without knowing the specifics of your situation.

Comment: Consider a photo-sharing site for instance. What would your answer be? Edited my question, please take a look.